# Wrap DotNetNuke menu in different Divs and specify CssClass?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want to group menu items in DNN menu into their own Divs - so I can have bottom padding on each cell in the hierarchy.

So for example:

I have main menu item of "About" - underneath that I have "About our Offices" - then under that I have "About our Server Room". This isn't the exact usage, just an example of the hierarchy.

I would like "About" to be the main tab, then when I hover that I can see my two other items, one nested in the other. However, I want "About our Offices" to be a Div with bottom padding separating it from the next 2nd level menu item.

So it would look like:

About

---

About our Offices

```
  About our Server Room
```

---

!!!padding here to separate second level menu items!!

---

Contact Us

```
    How to get here
```

---

Any ideas how to accomplish this? If I could just assign CssClass to each menu item that would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Solpart menu this is kind of hard you should look at some of the other menu providers

Answer (score 1):

I used `[/tr tr]` in my page name...